# iCloud error to open the document in iOS

Tags: ios, icloud

I have demo which was working perfect.
But somehow  it give error :-

```
(A Document Being Saved By Testappiclound)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 20.
```

Please help me how to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `errno` is 20, that means `ENOTDIR`, "not a directory". It's impossible to give a better answer unless you describe what you were doing at the time. The usual error reporting mechanism on iOS is `NSError`, which is returned from many, many methods and typically provides details of what specifically went wrong. Using `errno` is not necessarily wrong but is much less likely to give useful information.